# Solving for variable inside a sum

Tags: summation, fourier-series, dirichlet-series

So a few calcuations have ultimately led me to this expression

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_n^2\left( \sinh\left( \sqrt 2\, \pi n \right) - \sqrt 2\,\pi n \right)}{4\pi\sqrt 2\, n} = 1 $$

Is there any way one can solve for $B_n$ in this case?

Comment: If you get $B_n^2 = \text{something}$ then you've still got $B_n = \pm(\text{something})$ with no apparent way to decide between $\text{“}{+}\text{''}$ and $\text{“}{-}\text{''}. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't if you don't make more assumptions.

All $B_n$ could be $0$ except one of them that would be whatever it takes to make the sum equal to $1$.

Or all $B_n$ except one could be *anything at all* such that the series converges, and the remaining $B_n$ whatever it takes to make the sum $1$.